# Debugging AttributeError: ResultObject: Get attribute save not found

Tags: arcpy, python, spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.4

Below is the script for batch clipping of multiple raster images using a single shapefile.

```
import arcpy, glob, os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

# Set the input workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = r"F:\madhavi\images_to_clip"

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Absolute path to your mask layer
mask = r"F:\madhavi\shapefile\shp_gang_only_final.shp"

# Copying all the input rasters in an array
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()

# Loop through rasters, append names and save files
for raster in rasters:
    output_raster = raster.replace(".TIF", "_clip.TIF")
    rasterObject = arcpy.gp.ExtractByMask_sa(raster, mask, output_raster)
    rasterObject.save(r"F:\madhavi\clipped_images")
```

There are two problems that I am encountering with this script.

Firstly, the first output image is getting saved in the folder where the input images are stored and not in the desired folder where I want to save the output images.

Secondly, the for loop is not working beyond the first input image.

The screenshot of the error is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Python is case sensitive so you need to change to: output_raster = raster.replace(".tif", "_clip.tif"), otherwise the name will not be changed

Comment: Please always provide errors as text rather than pictures so that they are available to future searches by anyone else with the same question.

Answer (score 3):

For `output_raster.save` to work output_raster needs to be a [Raster Object](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/spatial-analyst/map-algebra/working-with-raster-objects.htm). In your case output_raster is a unicode object. This should work:

```
rasterObject = arpcy.gp.ExtractByMask_sa(raster, mask, output_raster)
rasterObject.save(r"C:\Path\rastername")
```

But i cant see why you even need the last line. The ExtractByMask should save your output? Also you should use "raw" when using backslashes in paths, like this: r"C:\path\raster". Otherwise the backslashes can cause problems.

Comment: I am still getting "Parsing Error SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal (line 18)". Therefore, there is a problem in "output_raster = raster.replace(".TIF", "_clip.TIF")".

Comment: @SujaiBappaBanerji Please **[edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/236859/edit)** your question to include this error message.  Can you also give some example filenames that this is failing on?